# Embedding video into an alert message

Tags: javascript, video, embed, alert

I am creating a web page using HTML and Javascript, I have included a help button using javascripts alert function so users get some information on how to use the web page.

I have researched endlessly to find out if it is possible to embed a video into an alert message. I have not found one web page that even comes to close to something like this, Is it even doable?

Comment: Jquery UI dialog - alert cannot show anything except plain text

Comment: again i barely recoment you to check out some jQuery Beginner Tutorials on Youtube or so. give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create you own javascript popup/alert/dialog box for the task or you can use [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or [Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals).
You cannot show anything except plain text in an alert box.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.alert):

```
window.alert(message);
```

> message is a string of text you want to display
>   in the alert dialog, or, alternatively, an object that is converted
>   into a string and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `alert(...)` function takes nothing but a string as parameter, these are your alternate options :

- [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)
- [Bootstrap Modal](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)